# Curated compound words

Tags: word, seasonal

Find a single word answer with the following property → compound words can be formed from the answer which have a word in common with compound words which can be formed from each of:

[image]

Text version:

```
EAGLE      FINAL     FLAG   HANDS    HARD    LEFT
MEDICINE   MORNING   POP    RAT'S    SHOCK   SUNDAY
```

- a different link word may be found for each of the 12 boxed words
- the compound word pairs are given as derived terms in Wiktionary

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking... maybe could you provide an example?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil For each element in the table A, there are two compound words B-A (or A-B), and B-C (or C-B), such that C is the same for all A.

Comment: This is a fun puzzle - thanks for posting!

Comment: Thanks @puzzledPig! It was easy to make - but perhaps hard to solve. The form of the image (including the number of words) was a hint.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that - clever!  The "seasonal" tag was definitely appreciated, though :)

Comment: Now, the link words would go...  OK, probably no hidden message there...  (Makes sense, it would probably be hard to construct a hidden message from the limited choices available.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> Egg.

Eagle:

> Eagle -> golden eagle -> golden egg -> egg.  (First solved by: @puzzledPig)

Final:

> Final -> cup final -> egg cup -> egg.  (First solved by: @Statman)

Flag:

> Flag -> white flag -> egg white -> egg.  (First solved by: @puzzledPig)

Hands:

> Hands -> hands-on -> egg on -> egg.  (First solved by: @puzzledPig / @Paige Meinke)

Hard:

> Hard -> hardboiled -> boiled egg -> egg.

Left:

> Left -> leftover -> over-egg -> egg.  (First solved by: @puzzledPig)

Medicine:

> Medicine -> bad medicine -> bad egg -> egg.

Morning:

> Morning -> good morning -> good egg -> egg.  (First solved by: @puzzledPig)

Pop:

> Pop -> Pop Tart -> egg tart -> egg.

Rat's:

> Rat's -> Rat's nest -> nest egg -> egg.

Shock:

> Shock -> shell shock -> eggshell -> egg.  (With thanks to @Statman for a comment hinting at this answer.)

Sunday:

> Sunday -> Easter Sunday -> Easter egg -> egg.  (Here's the most explicit "seasonal" part.)

And finally, as the OP had to point out to everybody, the form of the table looks roughly like:

> an egg carton with a dozen "eggs".

Comment: I keep thinking maybe "pop" is connected through "timer" - but that would be more "popup timer" I think...

Comment: Hmm... or inspired by the Wiktionary page, I almost want to say "pop tart" - but that's more a brand name than a compound word.

Comment: One of your answers for "hard" works with one of the other words.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - the name you suggest for "pop" is what fits overall to give 12 distinct link words (and is in Wiktionary as a derived term CW) even though you're right it is a brand - hope OK.

Comment: It's such a commonly used brand name I suppose it's basically a compound word now...

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I've added that one to my answer now.

Comment: It seems we have a solution - I'm editing my answer to incorporate contributions from puzzledPig and Statman and form it into a complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to what Daniel has with [his second answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62271/38170) (he did the hard work, upvote that one!):

Eagle:

> Eagle --> golden eagle --> golden egg --> egg.

Flag:

> Flag --> white flag --> egg white --> egg.

Left:

> Left --> left over --> [over-egg](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/over-egg) --> egg.

Morning:

> Morning --> good morning --> good egg --> egg.

Alternatively, suggested by Paige:

Hands:

> Hands --> hands-on --> egg on --> egg.

Now all that's missing is "final"...

Comment: I don't think the pop one is in wiki, perhaps swap it out for the hands?

Comment: Though your "pop" fits it's useful, as Paige says, to keep the 2 letter link word for "hands".

Comment: Your "left" is right!

Comment: Hmm, so what goes with final... exam, cause?  What other compound words with the answer haven't been used yet...  goose, timer, cup, carton, fried, poached, scrambled, hunt?  Still not finding any overlap...

Answer (score 3):

I shall sneak in with the final answer (no pun intended)

Final

> Cup final -> Egg cup

Answer (score 2):

**Very partial**, essentially just articulating some of my thoughts on possibilities in case somebody else might pick up on them.

Eagle:

> Eagle -> spread-eagle -> bedspread -> bed?

Medicine:

> Medicine -> medicine ball?

Final:

> Final -> final exam?

Morning:

> Morning -> morning glory?

Hands:

> Hands -> jazz hands -> jazz ensemble -> ensemble? (probably not)

Hard:

> Hard -> hard candy -> rock candy -> rock?

(Of course, none of these are exactly "seasonal".)